# optimize pymssql code

Tags: python, optimization, pymssql

i am inserting records to sql server from python using pymssql. The database takes 2 milliseconds to execute a query, yet it insert 6 rows per second. The only problem is at code side. how to optimize following code or what is the fastest method to insert records.

```
def save(self):
    conn = pymssql.connect(host=dbHost, user=dbUser, 
                           password=dbPassword, database=dbName, as_dict=True)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    self.pageURL = self.pageURL.replace("'","''")

    query = "my query is there"               
    cur.execute(query)

    conn.commit() 
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're creating a new connection per insert there. That's probably the major reason for the slowdown: building new connections is typically quite slow. Create the connection outside the method and you should see a large improvement. You can also create a cursor outside function and re-use it, which will be another speedup.

Depending on your situation, you may also want to use the same transaction for more than a single insertion. This changes the behaviour a little -- since a transaction is supposed to be atomic and either completely succeeds or completely fails -- but committing a transaction is typically a slow operation, because it has to be certain the whole operation succeeded.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks It works. I have already tried by the connection object outside method but speed was still low. when set autocommit property to True, than the speed is improved.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Thomas' great advice,
I'd suggest you look into `executemany()`*, [e.g.](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/wiki/PymssqlExamples):

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO persons VALUES(%d, %s)", 
    [ (1, 'John Doe'), (2, 'Jane Doe') ])
```

...where the second argument of `executemany()` should be a sequence of rows to insert.

This brings up another point:
You probably want to send your query and query parameters **as separate arguments** to either `execute()` or `executemany()`.  This will allow the PyMSSQL module to handle any quoting issues for you.

*`executemany()` as described in the [Python DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/):

> `.executemany(operation,seq_of_parameters)`
>   Prepare a database operation (query or
>   command) and then execute it against
>   all parameter sequences or mappings
>   found in the sequence
>   seq_of_parameters.